# Using basemap to plot tax trips in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to use the `Basemap` function to create a plot like the one shown [here](https://www.kaggle.com/dotman/data-exploration-and-visualization/notebook), but using [this](https://www.kaggle.com/c/nyc-taxi-trip-duration/data) data.

This is my code:

```
west, south, east, north = -74.26, 40.50, -73.70, 40.92

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,10))

m = Basemap(projection='merc', llcrnrlat=south, urcrnrlat=north,
            llcrnrlon=west, urcrnrlon=east, lat_ts=south, resolution='c')
x, y = m(df['pickup_longitude'].values, df['pickup_latitude'].values)
m.hexbin(x, y, gridsize=1900, cmap=cm.YlOrRd_r)
```

However, my result is nothing but weird.

[image]

I'm wondering what I'm missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the data comprises much more data than in the range inside the Basemap plot.
You will get the desired plot by using a lot more gridpoints, e.g. `gridsize=10000`.  This will however cost a lot of memory.

A better option would probably be to first select from the dataframe those values that are in the range to be shown in the map.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib import cm

df = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
west, south, east, north = -74.26, 40.50, -73.70, 40.92
df = df[(df['pickup_longitude'] > west) & (df['pickup_longitude'] < east)]
df = df[(df['pickup_latitude'] > south) & (df['pickup_latitude'] < north)]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))

m = Basemap(projection='merc', llcrnrlat=south, urcrnrlat=north,
            llcrnrlon=west, urcrnrlon=east, lat_ts=south, resolution='c')
x, y = m(df['pickup_longitude'].values, df['pickup_latitude'].values)
m.hexbin(x, y, gridsize=100, bins='log', cmap=cm.YlOrRd_r, lw=0.4)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Using a more gridpoints then allows for even finer resolution. E.g. `gridsize=1000`:

[image]